# Python sympy dsolve error

Tags: python, sympy, dsolve

After reinstalling Python, the following simple code

```
import sympy as sm

x = sm.Symbol('x')

f = sm.Function('f')

y = sm.dsolve(sm.diff(f (x),x)-3*f(x)(1-0.5f(x)),f(x))

print(y)
```

gives the following output:

```
Eq(x + 0.333333333333333*log(1.0*f(x) - 2.0) - 0.333333333333333*log(1.0*f(x)), C1)
```

but before it used to give me the right answer:
`f(x) == -2.0/(C1*exp(-3.0*x) - 1.0)`.

Can someone help me to fix this, please?

Comment: Please format your code properly by [edit]ing it. Also remove those line numbers. And what do you mean "it used to give" you the right answer? Please read [ask].

Comment: What version of sympy were you using previously? What version are you using here? 

I also notice that there are some syntax errors in the code that's posted. Would it be possible to post code that actually gives the output you displayed?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `Rational` instead of float number, as follow:

```
>>> import sympy as sym
>>> x = sym.Symbol('x')
>>> f = sym.Function('f')(x)
>>> y = sym.dsolve(sym.diff(f,x)-3*f*(1-sym.Rational(1, 2)*f),f)
>>> print y
Eq(f(x), -2/(C1*exp(-3*x) - 1))
```

Comment: Don't you need a module name for that `Rational`?

Comment: Sorry, Rational is a sympy class, I forgot to write the "sym" prefix before. Thanks for your note.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am sorry about the syntax and editing mistakes in the first post.
Actually, right now I am running exactly the same code in two computers, one with Anaconda for Windows other with Spyder for Ubuntu, both have Python 2.7, and got two different answers. The code is:

```
import sympy as sm

x = sm.Symbol('x')
f = sm.Function('f')(x)

y=sm.dsolve(sm.diff(f,x)-3*f*(1-0.5*f),f)
print(y)
```

In the Ubuntu version I obtain the explicit solution 
`f(x) == -2.0/(C1*exp(-3.0*x) - 1.0)`
While in the windows machine I obtain the implicit solution
`Eq(x + 0.3333333333333*log(1.0*f(x) - 2.0) - 0.333333333333*log(1.0*f(x)), C1)`